# Python: Sort default dictionary of lists

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, defaultdict

I have dictionary of lists that I need to sort by the first value in the list. I'm using a defaultdict.

```
from collections import defaultdict
Dict = defaultdict(list)
Dict['A'].append([100, 'abcd'])
Dict['A'].append([50, 'bgfd'])
Dict['A'].append([150, 'abcd'])
```

I need to iterate over the dictionary in an ordered manner so that I get:

```
for Entry in Dict['A']:
     print Entry
```

Should give:

```
[50, 'bgfd']
[100, 'abcd']
[150, 'abcd']
```

Comment: You can't sort dictionaries, they're unordered. What you want to do is sort the list values in a `defaultdict(list)`. That's fine as list _are_ ordered. You can get a sorted _copy_ of an entry by using `sorted(Dict['A'])`, or you could actually reorder the contents of one by using `Dict['A'].sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

The value is *just* a list, so you can sort it with [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
for Entry in sorted(Dict['A']):
    print Entry
```

Sorting is lexicographical on the contents of the list; so first ordering is determined by `list_a[0]` vs. `list_b[0]`, then if those tie, elements 1 are compared, etc.

All this has nothing to do with the `defaultdict`, that's just the container for the keys and values, but you already retrieved the value.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> Dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> Dict['A'].append([100, 'abcd'])
>>> Dict['A'].append([50, 'bgfd'])
>>> Dict['A'].append([150, 'abcd'])
>>> sorted(Dict['A'])
[[50, 'bgfd'], [100, 'abcd'], [150, 'abcd']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and sort the list stored in `Dict['A']`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> Dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> Dict['A'].append([100, 'abcd'])
>>> Dict['A'].append([50, 'bgfd'])
>>> Dict['A'].append([150, 'abcd'])
>>>
>>> for Entry in sorted(Dict['A']):
...     print Entry
...
[50, 'bgfd']
[100, 'abcd']
[150, 'abcd']
>>>
```